# Android Studio on Lubuntu guest in VirtualBox?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I would like to use Android Studio on Lubuntu as guest in VirtualBox.

The installation works fine but I can't get the "hello world" app to run on any AVD (Android Virtual Device)

Lubuntu 32 bit:

- ARM won't work, abd connection error
- USB > AVD manager won't work

Lubuntu 64 bit:

- It's complaining about VtX settings

What is the best environment? 32 of 64 bit? And what is the fastest and easiest way to test my app? AVD, ARM, USB (hardware device) or another VirtualBox with Android on it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue on Windows host as well.. I guess the issue here is that VirtualBox still lacks the ability to host VT-in-VT. Please see: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032